# Unable to load Vim plugins on Ubuntu trusty64

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, vim-plugin

I'm using Vagrant and VirtualBox to set-up and provision a Ubuntu Trusty machine. During the provisioning stage I'm downloading my dotfiles (which include my `.vimrc` and `.tmux.conf` files as well as my `.vim` folder).

My `.tmux.conf` works fine but I discovered that my `.vimrc` was failing to load my plugins (I use the Pathogen plugin manager) and so when I start Vim I see errors about certain colour schemes not being found (because the particular colour scheme is loaded via a plugin) and also some other plugin related settings within my .vimrc are causing errors to be displayed.

Below is my `Vagrantfile` (not that it's relevant but in case you're wondering what box I'm using to up the Linux instance from):

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "172.17.8.100"
  config.vm.synced_folder "./Application", "/www", create: true

  config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    s.privileged = true
    s.path = "provision.sh"
  end

  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.ssh.forward_x11 = true
end
```

The full provisioning script can be viewed here: https://github.com/Integralist/Linux-and-Docker-Development-Environment/blob/master/provision.sh but the important section (i.e. the git cloning of my dotfiles and checking out the relevant `linux` branch) is as follows:

```
dotfiles_location=/home/vagrant/dotfiles
git clone https://github.com/Integralist/dotfiles.git $dotfiles_location
cd $dotfiles_location && git fetch && git checkout linux
shopt -s extglob
mv !(.|..|.git|README.md) ..
```

In the above snippet I'm moving all the dotfiles (i.e. `.vimrc`, `.vim` and `.tmux.conf`) into `/home/vagrant/` (note: the files specified inside the parentheses aren't being moved though, like the `.git` folder).

When I execute `vim` I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing /home/vagrant/.vimrc:
line  125:
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'Tomorrow-Night'
```

And then within Vim it errors again:

```
Error detected while processing VimEnter Auto commands for "*":
E492: Not an editor command: RainbowParenthesesToggle
```

I've looked at other Linux related issues on the Pathogen repo but I can't determine where the problem is coming from?

Executing `:scriptnames` returns:

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
  7: ~/.vimrc
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/nosyntax.vim
  9: ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftoff.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim
 13: ~/.vim/plugin/BufOnly.vim
 14: ~/.vim/plugin/scratch.vim
 15: ~/.vim/bundle/ZoomWin/plugin/ZoomWinPlugin.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 23: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
 24: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 25: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
```

Executing `:set rtp` returns:

```
runtimepath=
~/.vim,
/var/lib/vim/addons,
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,
/usr/share/vim/vim74,
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,
/var/lib/vim/addons/after,
~/.vim/after
```

Executing `:set compatible?` returns `nocompatible`

Executing `:set loadplugins?` returns `loadplugins`

Looking at the `:scriptnames` output it seems like maybe the `.vimrc` is being loaded before the pathogen file? But if that's the case I'm not sure how to resolve that so it's always loaded first? I spoke with Tim Pope (author of Pathogen) on GitHub about it and he suggested:

> "It's your vimrc's job to load pathogen.vim so the ordering is correct. Confirm how you're invoking pathogen and the directory structure of your Vim directory"

I then replied with the following clarification (Note: I heard nothing back, hence I'm now here looking for help)...

My full dotfile structure can be seen here: https://github.com/Integralist/dotfiles (technically it's the `linux` branch).

Specifically I call it here: https://github.com/Integralist/dotfiles/blob/linux/.vimrc#L119-L120

Note: these dotfiles work fine on my Mac and it's only since loading them on a Linux machine have I noticed an issue with plugins not being loaded by Pathogen.

The top level tree structure can be seen below...

```
.
├── .agignore
├── .bashrc
├── .gitconfig
├── .gitignore_global
├── .irssi
├── .tmux.conf
├── .vim
│   ├── .netrwhist
│   ├── autoload
│   │   └── pathogen.vim
│   ├── bundle
│   │   ├── CSApprox
│   │   ├── Dockerfile.vim
│   │   ├── Gist.vim
│   │   ├── Tabmerge
│   │   ├── ZoomWin
│   │   ├── ack.vim
│   │   ├── camelcasemotion
│   │   ├── ctrlp.vim
│   │   ├── emmet-vim
│   │   ├── gruvbox
│   │   ├── html5.vim
│   │   ├── nerdtree
│   │   ├── rainbow_parentheses.vim
│   │   ├── supertab
│   │   ├── syntastic
│   │   ├── tabular
│   │   ├── targets.vim
│   │   ├── textutil.vim
│   │   ├── tomorrow-night-vim
│   │   ├── vim-airline
│   │   ├── vim-bookmarks
│   │   ├── vim-choosewin
│   │   ├── vim-clojure-highlight
│   │   ├── vim-clojure-static
│   │   ├── vim-colors-pencil
│   │   ├── vim-commentary
│   │   ├── vim-cucumber
│   │   ├── vim-dispatch
│   │   ├── vim-endwise
│   │   ├── vim-fireplace
│   │   ├── vim-fugitive
│   │   ├── vim-gitgutter
│   │   ├── vim-haml
│   │   ├── vim-leiningen
│   │   ├── vim-localrc
│   │   ├── vim-markdown
│   │   ├── vim-node
│   │   ├── vim-polyglot
│   │   ├── vim-repeat
│   │   ├── vim-ruby
│   │   ├── vim-sexp
│   │   ├── vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people
│   │   ├── vim-surround
│   │   ├── vim-tbone
│   │   ├── webapi-vim
│   │   └── wildfire.vim
│   ├── colors
│   │   ├── Tomorrow-Solarized.vim
│   │   ├── badwolf.vim
│   │   ├── blazer.vim
│   │   ├── flatland.vim
│   │   ├── github.vim
│   │   ├── gruvbox.vim
│   │   ├── kellys.vim
│   │   ├── vividchalk.vim
│   │   └── whitebox.vim
│   └── plugin
│       ├── BufOnly.vim
│       └── scratch.vim
├── .vimrc
```

I've since tried deleting all plugins from the `bundle` directory and putting back in the `tomorrow-night-vim` plugin folder but still Vim can't find the plugin so when I execute `:colorscheme Tomorrow` it fails to locate that file (this was in the hope that maybe there was another plugin that was causing a problem and stopping all other plugins from loading -> clutching at straws on that one I know).

The following output is from running `:scriptnames` on a similar set-up on my Mac:

```
~/.vimrc
  2: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.335/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.335/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.335/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.335/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
  6: ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
  7: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.335/share/vim/vim74/ftoff.vim
  8: ~/.vim/bundle/Dockerfile.vim/ftdetect/Dockerfile.vim
  9: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-clojure-static/ftdetect/clojure.vim
 10: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-cucumber/ftdetect/cucumber.vim
 11: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-haml/ftdetect/haml.vim
 12: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-markdown/ftdetect/markdown.vim
 13: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-node/ftdetect/node.vim
 14: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-polyglot/ftdetect/polyglot.vim
 15: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-ruby/ftdetect/ruby.vim
 16: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-polyglot/after/ftdetect/rspec.vim
 17: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.335/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
 18: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.335/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim
 19: ~/.vim/bundle/tomorrow-night-vim/colors/Tomorrow-Night.vim
 20: ~/.vim/plugin/BufOnly.vim
 21: ~/.vim/plugin/scratch.vim
 22: ~/.vim/bundle/ack.vim/plugin/ack.vim
 23: ~/.vim/bundle/camelcasemotion/plugin/camelcasemotion.vim
 24: ~/.vim/bundle/CSApprox/plugin/CSApprox.vim
 25: ~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim/plugin/ctrlp.vim
 26: ~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim/autoload/ctrlp/mrufiles.vim
 27: ~/.vim/bundle/emmet-vim/plugin/emmet.vim
 28: ~/.vim/bundle/Gist.vim/plugin/gist.vim
 29: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/plugin/NERD_tree.vim
 30: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/autoload/nerdtree.vim
 31: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/path.vim
 32: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/menu_controller.vim
```

Comment: OK it looks like my plugins haven't been uploaded to GitHub :-/ I'm not sure why though. I need to figure out how to upload folders that are themselves git repos (e.g. they have a .git file) then that will resolve the problem I'm having.

Comment: Try moving line 118-120 to the top of the file, *before* line 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the problem wasn't with Pathogen but with Git and it not committing my submodules. Apparently there is a way to work around this using a .gitmodules file but I didn't have time to investigate it further so I solved the problem using some basic Unix commands:

`find . -type d -name '.git' | xargs rm -rf`

I then was able to commit the contents of the submodule folders